# Using lxml to parse xml with multiple namespaces

Tags: python, xpath, soap, lxml

I'm pulling xml from a SOAP api that looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ae="urn:sbmappservices72" xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:diag="urn:SerenaDiagnostics" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ae:GetItemsByQueryResponse>
      <ae:return>
        <ae:item>
          <ae:id xsi:type="ae:ItemIdentifier">
            <ae:displayName/>
            <ae:id>10</ae:id>
            <ae:uuid>a9b91034-8f4d-4043-b9b6-517ba4ed3a33</ae:uuid>
            <ae:tableId>1541</ae:tableId>
            <ae:tableIdItemId>1541:10</ae:tableIdItemId>
            <ae:issueId/>
          </ae:id>
```

I can't for the life of me use findall to pull something like tableId. Most of the tutorials on parsing using lxml don't include namespaces, but [the one at lxml.de](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes) does, and I've been trying to follow it.

According to their tutorial you should create a dictionary of the namespaces, which I've done like so:

```
r = tree.xpath('/e:SOAP-ENV/s:ae', 
        namespaces={'e': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
                    's': 'urn:sbmappservices72'})
```

But that appears to not be working, as when I try to get the len of r, it comes back as 0:

```
print 'length: ' + str(len(r)) #<---- always equals 0
```

Since the URI for the second namespace is a "urn:", I tried using a real URL to the wsdl as well, but that gives me the same result.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I just need to be able to pull values like the one for tableIdItemId.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fact that one of the namespaces is defined using a URN does not matter. It is just as valid as a URL.

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed so, but since it wasn't working I wasn't certain. I'd give you an upvote if I could :]

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath doesn't correctly corresponds to the XML structure. Try this way instead :

```
r = tree.xpath('/e:Envelope/e:Body/s:GetItemsByQueryResponse/s:return/s:item/s:id/s:tableId', 
        namespaces={'e': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
                    's': 'urn:sbmappservices72'})
```

For small XML, you may want to use `//` instead of `/` to simplify the expression, for example :

```
r = tree.xpath('/e:Envelope/e:Body//s:tableId', 
        namespaces={'e': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
                    's': 'urn:sbmappservices72'})
```

`/e:Body//s:tableId` will find `tableId` no matter how depth it is nested within `Body`. Note however that `//` surely slower than `/` especially when applied for a huge XML.